# how can I make a two colour curved line progress bar that responsive with React.js and TailwindCSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm having a difficulties making a curved line progress bar.
Don't get me wrong, I'm able to make a straight line progress bar (more or less like this expectation) using div with TailwindCSS, but this... this curved line progress bar has struck my head so hard.

here is the expectation
[image]

yes, the rocket will progressed going forward from the middle of the curved line to the edge of the line.
and the bar will filled with the darker colour according to the step that user take.
Somehow I managed to make the rocket go forward-backward according to the step that user take but the trajectory is straight, not curved.

for now, I export that line from Figma file to an SVG, then I stack it (brighter yellow, darker yellow, then the rocket). And I made that rocket static.

here's the code

```
    {activeIndex === 2 && (
      // using SVG
      <div className="flex w-screen justify-center absolute bottom-28 -left-3 z-50 px-40">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-max relative">
          <svg
            className="absolute z-40"
            // style={{ left: "93%", top: "56%", rotate: "27deg" }}
            style={{
              left: `${activeProgress < 95 ? 45 : 93}%`,
              top: `${activeProgress < 95 ? 0 : 56}%`,
              rotate: `${activeProgress < 95 ? 0 : 27}deg`,
            }}
            width="96"
            height="77"
            viewBox="0 0 96 77"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M36.44 63.35C37.3775 62.5957 38.5722 62.237 39.7701 62.35C56.0401 63.93 73.8899 63.6699 91.1099 53.7599C92.379 53.0179 93.4545 51.9862 94.2486 50.7491C95.0427 49.512 95.533 48.1046 95.6793 46.6418C95.8256 45.1791 95.6238 43.7025 95.0904 42.3327C94.557 40.9628 93.7069 39.7386 92.6099 38.7599C77.7199 25.6099 60.2603 21.7599 44.0103 20.1199C42.8177 19.999 41.7176 19.4222 40.94 18.5099L28.1402 3.32994C27.2932 2.33208 26.0924 1.70125 24.7901 1.56993L10.15 0.0799429C9.68518 0.0316988 9.21609 0.10628 8.78914 0.296252C8.3622 0.486224 7.9927 0.784949 7.71737 1.16252C7.44203 1.5401 7.27018 1.98328 7.21981 2.44786C7.16944 2.91244 7.24224 3.38211 7.43026 3.80992L12.1202 14.48C12.4413 15.2156 12.5688 16.0211 12.4903 16.8199L8.23006 59.2999C8.14933 60.0944 7.86726 60.8551 7.41024 61.5099L0.680257 71.03C0.413786 71.4132 0.251426 71.8593 0.209554 72.3242C0.167681 72.7891 0.247787 73.257 0.441487 73.6817C0.635187 74.1064 0.936026 74.4734 1.31453 74.7466C1.69304 75.0198 2.13606 75.1898 2.60018 75.2399L17.2403 76.6999C18.5424 76.8354 19.8456 76.4549 20.8702 75.6399L36.44 63.35ZM61.88 50.28C60.499 50.1498 59.1878 49.6122 58.1129 48.7355C57.0379 47.8588 56.2476 46.6825 55.8424 45.3559C55.4371 44.0293 55.4354 42.6121 55.837 41.2844C56.2385 39.9567 57.0252 38.7782 58.0977 37.8985C59.1702 37.0189 60.4803 36.4777 61.8609 36.3436C63.2416 36.2096 64.6309 36.4887 65.8526 37.1457C67.0743 37.8026 68.0728 38.8077 68.7223 40.0334C69.3717 41.2591 69.6426 42.6502 69.5001 44.03C69.3105 45.8659 68.4032 47.5527 66.9762 48.7232C65.5491 49.8937 63.7175 50.4532 61.88 50.28Z"
              fill="#4C2A70"
            />
          </svg>
          <svg
            className="absolute z-30 left-0 right-0"
            width="1100"
            height="239"
            viewBox="0 0 1434 239"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M27.3399 236.08C48.2699 221.01 70.9704 208.08 93.5104 195.64C119.35 181.373 145.714 168.113 172.6 155.86C180.794 152.113 189.02 148.447 197.28 144.86L202.65 142.55L205.9 141.17C209.76 139.51 202.1 142.75 205.99 141.17C210.457 139.303 214.933 137.45 219.42 135.61C238.153 127.983 257.047 120.783 276.1 114.01C319.344 98.6383 363.337 85.4615 407.91 74.5299C432.577 68.4766 457.417 63.1165 482.43 58.4499C495.764 55.9565 509.14 53.6699 522.56 51.5899C528.84 50.6099 535.124 49.6766 541.41 48.7899L546.6 48.0699C552.32 47.2699 543.03 48.5299 548.77 47.7799C552.27 47.3199 555.77 46.8699 559.26 46.4299C680.433 31.4101 803.09 33.0082 923.83 51.1799C1072.07 73.8299 1216.01 120.86 1350.61 186.69C1369.35 195.857 1387.92 205.367 1406.33 215.22C1414.9 219.8 1425.92 217.38 1430.96 208.76C1435.73 200.6 1433.1 188.76 1424.5 184.14C1286 110.14 1137.4 54.3299 982.95 24.9599C857.6 1.12989 729.16 -5.81013 602.06 5.81987C498.635 15.2203 396.601 36.2703 297.9 68.5699C227.65 91.6299 158.96 120.23 93.5602 154.76C65.1002 169.76 36.4603 185.59 10.2003 204.3L9.2003 205.03C1.3203 210.71 -2.49966 220.7 2.74033 229.66C7.29034 237.44 19.4402 241.83 27.3702 236.12L27.3399 236.08Z"
              fill="#FFC100"
            />
          </svg>
          <svg
            width="1100"
            height="239"
            viewBox="0 0 1434 239"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M27.3399 236.08C48.2699 221.01 70.9704 208.08 93.5104 195.64C119.35 181.373 145.714 168.113 172.6 155.86C180.794 152.113 189.02 148.447 197.28 144.86L202.65 142.55L205.9 141.17C209.76 139.51 202.1 142.75 205.99 141.17C210.457 139.303 214.933 137.45 219.42 135.61C238.153 127.983 257.047 120.783 276.1 114.01C319.344 98.6383 363.337 85.4615 407.91 74.5299C432.577 68.4766 457.417 63.1165 482.43 58.4499C495.764 55.9565 509.14 53.6699 522.56 51.5899C528.84 50.6099 535.124 49.6766 541.41 48.7899L546.6 48.0699C552.32 47.2699 543.03 48.5299 548.77 47.7799C552.27 47.3199 555.77 46.8699 559.26 46.4299C680.433 31.4101 803.09 33.0082 923.83 51.1799C1072.07 73.8299 1216.01 120.86 1350.61 186.69C1369.35 195.857 1387.92 205.367 1406.33 215.22C1414.9 219.8 1425.92 217.38 1430.96 208.76C1435.73 200.6 1433.1 188.76 1424.5 184.14C1286 110.14 1137.4 54.3299 982.95 24.9599C857.6 1.12989 729.16 -5.81013 602.06 5.81987C498.635 15.2203 396.601 36.2703 297.9 68.5699C227.65 91.6299 158.96 120.23 93.5602 154.76C65.1002 169.76 36.4603 185.59 10.2003 204.3L9.2003 205.03C1.3203 210.71 -2.49966 220.7 2.74033 229.66C7.29034 237.44 19.4402 241.83 27.3702 236.12L27.3399 236.08Z"
              fill="#FFE8BB"
            />
          </svg>
          <p
            className="text-center font-bold text-xl text-white absolute left-8 bottom-8"
            style={{ transform: "rotate(-30deg)" }}
          >
            Rocket Launch
          </p>
          <p className="text-center font-bold text-xl text-white absolute left-0 right-0 top-16 z-40">
            Galaxy Minat
          </p>
          <p
            className="text-center font-bold text-xl text-white absolute right-8 bottom-10 z-40"
            style={{ transform: "rotate(25deg)" }}
          >
            Touch Down
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
```

and here's the front that I made
[image]

please. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please include the necessary code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't debug code that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Reyno well, it's not technically a bug, it's more "I don't know how to code that, so I improvise and still doesn't know how". anyway, I've updated the question. thx a lot for helping me